# proftpd: mod_sftp connection timeout

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, timeout, proftpd

I'm using an SFTP Server based on proftpd's mod_sftp. 
The only problem is, that I haven't found a way to keep idle connections for longer then a few minutes.

Our users request idle times for up to a whole day.

I have played arround with the option `SFTPKeepAlive`, but the session are still disconnecting.

Is there another option I have overlooked or is there another spot to search (e.g. `openssh` or `pam`)?

Here is a snip of the proftpd.log:

```
Mär 20 11:03:34 sftp01 proftpd: SSH2 session opened.
Mär 20 11:03:38 sftp01 proftpd: Preparing to chroot to directory '/srv/sftp/homes/user'
Mär 20 11:03:38 sftp01 proftpd: USER user: Login successful
Mär 20 11:03:38 sftp01 proftpd: USER user: Login successful.
[...]
Mär 20 11:20:31 sftp01 proftp: SSH2 no transfer timeout, disconnected
Mär 20 11:20:31 sftp01 proftpd: SSH2 session closed.
Mär 20 11:20:40 sftp01 proftpd: SSH2 session opened.
```

Thank you and greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post your `proftpd.conf` file, which would be really helpful. However, it sounds like you haven't explicitly set [`TimeoutIdle`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TimeoutIdle.html) in your `proftpd.conf` file.

Add this to your file:

```
# Timeout after 3600 seconds (60 minutes)
TimeoutIdle 3600
```

If you already have something like that, then post your conf file so we can better help you. Obviously, just increase that to however long you want the connection to sit idle before it times out.

Also, you can review the full documentation for [`mod_sftp` here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html).

Comment: In addition to David's answer, You say that your users request idle times up to a whole day. You will have to verify other network components in the chain (like firewalls) also which might close inactive sessions. Besides that you might need to enable KeepAlive to ensure that connections won't be dropped.

Comment: i must have been blind... the option is already set in my config file.... i must have gone over a hundred times...